# Gitlab install fails at gitlab-ctl reconfigure

Tags: linux, git, postgresql, debian, gitlab

So, I have been following GitLab's install guide (on Debian Stretch) and I always get the same error...

The link: https://about.gitlab.com/install/#debian

The error:

```
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:
execute[/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D p /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data -E UTF8 (postgresql::enable line 80) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data -E UTF8 ----
STDOUT: The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "gitlab-psql".
This user must also own the server process.
STDERR: initdb: invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables
---- End output of /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data -E UTF8 ----
Ran /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/initdb -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data -E UTF8 returned 1
```

I have tried some things, but since I cannot find this issue elsewhere, it didn't get me far. I am not that experienced with Linux, so I would appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What platform are you running on? I've done this exact process on AWS instance with no problems. Also: "STDOUT: The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "gitlab-psql".
This user must also own the server process." This suggests you've switched users between installation and reconfiguring.

Comment: @Oren_C Well, I am trying to install the Omnibus build of Gitlab on my home Debian Stretch, and the process fails even when running every command by itself (which shouldn't switch users). I also didn't change users manually, and did everything with a consistent use of Sudo.

Comment: Let's start with the beginning. Could you add to your question the failure that you receive when just starting the process? There's no need to continue with the instructions if the process fails at some point. Let's figure out what's holding you back on the beginning.

Comment: Whether I run gitlab-ctl reconfigure myself or let the install process do its thing, the message I pasted is the only error message I get, and it never changes.

Comment: Have you done any changes to locale settings? This repeats itself:
"invalid locale settings; check LANG and LC_* environment variables"

Comment: Well, I set it up to use FR-fr and an azerty keyboard, but I didn't change anything per se.

Comment: I think this installation is not supported in FR-fr, try changing back to EN-us and try installing again.

Comment: I did that, and it didn't work any better... I even reconfigured the OS from scratch, and it did nothing. Do you think reinstalling Debian could be needed?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem are because you're using a latin collation.

Use any collation (LANG en_US.UTF-8) on UTF8.

If you're using Debian, do not change LANG or LC_ variables. Use this command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

On the interface, please select the desired interface (You can even try with fr_FR, but use always the utf8 option). Do not use LATIN or ISO_8859 alternatives.